# Sort Json Array with LoDash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have a JSON array whose general structure is like this:

```
var json = [ 
  { key: 'firstName', value: 'Bill' },
  { key: 'lastName',  value: 'Mans' },
  { key: 'phone', value: '123.456.7890' }
];
```

In reality, there will be a lot more key/value pairs. Either way, I'm trying to sort this array by the key value using [Lodash](http://lodash.com/). Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
_.map(_.sortBy(json, key), _.values);
```

However, that causes an error that says:

```
[ReferenceError: key is not defined]
```

I suspect its because key is not wrapped in quotes as shown in the [docs](http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy). Unfortunately, I do not actually have control over the format of the json. In reality its being used by other developers and I'm the last to use it. Is there a way for me to sort the json array, by key names, using lodash? If so, how?

thank you

Comment: This is not JSON, look at how JSON should be formatted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to put the key in quotes only when calling `sortBy`. It doesn't have to be in quotes in the data itself.

```
_.sortBy(json, "key")
```

Also, your second parameter to `map` is wrong. It should be a function, but using `pluck` is easier.

```
_.pluck( _.sortBy(json, "key") , "value");
```

Comment: why is it when I do console.log(json) after the call, the JSON isn't sorted? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: functions? `sortBy` and `pluck` return values; neither operates on in-place data.

Comment: I must be missing something. I want to say json = _.sortBy(json, "key"); console.log(json); At that point, I need the results to be sorted. For some reason, they're still not sorted using the approach listed above.

Comment: @StephenThomas how can I re arrange the array `json` itself instead of pluck, meaning returning a sorted new array

Answer (score 4):

```
_.map(_.sortBy(json, 'key'), 'value');
```

NOTE: In the latest version of lodash, `_.pluck` no longer exists.  Use `_.map` instead as a drop-in replacement